# How do I split this string with Js?

Tags: javascript, split

i been reading for hours trying to make this work but i dont have much knowledge to do it.

I have this js code:

```
var username=$(this).attr("username");
```

It pull a list of users f.e (admin, test1, test2, test3)

and i needs to split it into another var like this:

```
var members = [
    ['admin'],
    ['test1'],
    ['test2'],
    ['test3'],
];
```

I tried a lot of codes but i cant make it work, thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the usernames seperated by commas?

Comment: no, they dont ...will include space only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get an array of usernames:

```
var username = $(this).attr("username");
var members = username.split(',');
```

To get exactly what you've suggested you want (an array of arrays? - I don't think this is actually what you want):

```
var username = $(this).attr("username");
var membersArr = username.split(',');
var members = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < membersArr.length; i++)
{
    members[i] = [ membersArr[i] ];
}
```

To get "[test1]", "[test2]" etc:

```
var username = $(this).attr("username");
var members = username.split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++)
{
    members[i] = '[' + members[i] + ']';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. looks ok however i want to to get at the end the user list looks like this:     ['admin'],['test1'], ['test2'], ['test3'],  -  not just commas or spaces .. thanks!

Comment: @DJ-237. That doesn't really make sense. What you are describing there is a "list of lists". My second example provides that. Is that what you are really after? My first example gives you a "list of strings".

Comment: i'm sorry but im not a pro on this. I got an script that needs at the end a code like this var members = [
    ['admin'],
    ['test1'],
    ['test2'],
    ['test3'],
];
 The way you did it on second example works but it doesnt includes the username like this ['username'],

Comment: @DJ-237 DO you mean like this: "[username]" ?

Comment: I works now i just added like this :    members[i] = ["['" + membersArr[i] + "'],</br>" ];  thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

**Update**
To get the array of arrays,

```
var username=$(this).attr("username");
var membersArray= username.split(' ').map(function(username){
    return [username];
})
//[["admin"],["test"],["test1"],["test2"]]
```

I've added a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NVENA/)

Comment: Thanks, how can i get it into the members var like this?  var members = [
    ['admin'],
    ['test1'],
    ['test2'],
    ['test3'],
];